# Why is my create table QUERY generating this query automatically only for this table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

These are my Column Names declared in Java

```
public static final String TABLE_USER = "user_master";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String USER_ID = "user_id";
public static final String USER_FULLNAME = "user_fullname";
public static final String USER_MOBILE = "user_mobile";
public static final String USER_TYPE = "user_type";
public static final String USER_STATUS = "user_status";
```

This the create table statement generated

```
 String USER_MASTER = "CREATE TABLE user_master ( user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_fullname TEXT, user_mobile TEXT, user_type TEXT, user_status TEXT ); ";



String USER_MASTER = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER +  " ( "
        + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + USER_ID + "  INTEGER, "
        + USER_FULLNAME + "  TEXT, "
        + USER_MOBILE + "  TEXT, "
        + USER_TYPE + "  TEXT, "
        + USER_STATUS + "  TEXT ) ";

CREATE TABLE user_master(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_fullname TEXT, user_mobile TEXT, user_type TEXT, user_statusTEXT )
```

Here the  "user_statusTEXT" the TEXT word is getting appended automatically.

I just don't know why?

I tried it both ways in SQLiteOpenHelper to create this table, it is still not working

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to be behind the SQL you posted.

Comment: *FYI:* A `CREATE TABLE` *statement* is not a query. A `SELECT` statement is a query. The general definition of the word "query" should make that obvious: *query: a question*.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, but why is that happening.
Can you tell me.

Comment: It is a SQLite in Android using Java @laalto

Comment: I downvoted this over the massive lack of code. There is most likely a typo somewhere that calls the wrong creation statement. There's no way to reproduce the issue either, so I have voted to close this because of a missing MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to debug with the code given. However, the datatype specification of a column is optional in  Sqlite `CREATE TABLE` statement [see docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), so you could try removing all the TEXT datatypes and see what happens. So,

```
String USER_MASTER = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER +  " ( "
        + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + USER_ID + "  INTEGER, "
        + USER_FULLNAME + "  , "
        + USER_MOBILE + "  , "
        + USER_TYPE + " , "
        + USER_STATUS + " ) ";
```

Comment: how will that affect

Comment: i need it to be "TEXT" field
But when I change user_status as user_statusTEXT 
everything works smoothly

Comment: Try my code, sqlite does not need you to specify the column type, it does not use static typing. See https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html. I am not sure why the space between your column name and the TEXT datatype is being ignored, but it my code removes the error it should help you fault find.

Comment: It is as if your code is not  + USER_STATUS + "  TEXT ) "; but  + USER_STATUS + "TEXT ) "; It seems to ignore the space. My code removes the need for TEXT.

Comment: It is not working, why is it working for my other tables and not for this specific column and specific table??

Comment: Hey people I solved it myself, it gets resolved when you upgrade the database version of the app

Comment: @Shadab K good to hear that things are resolved.